# Ruby on Rails, View cannot find path for Collection routes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I added a collection routes which is POST in my routes

```
 resources: curated_items do
    collection do
      post 'duplicate'
    end
  end
```

but in my view cannot find path for this duplicate prefix.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SB5he.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6dQb.png)

here starting code for my partial template

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form role="form" action="<%= duplicate_curated_items_path %>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Select Client </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
```

Comment: can you please share code written for view and error if any?

Comment: @GaneshNavale u can check the image links too for the full code screenshot

Answer (score 0):

To access this route from a view you need:

```
duplicate_curated_items_path
```

or

```
duplicate_curated_items_url
```

Documentation:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

Comment: i did, see that image which i attatched, it says cannot find duplicate_curated_items_path :(

Comment: ah ok it wasn't clear that there are two attachments there :P. Do you have a #duplicate method in your curated items controller ?

Comment: Yup..It's blank I left it blank with no body on purpose

Comment: It's your IDE complaining. Have you tried running the code and see if it's actually working? if you get route not found errors?

Comment: And that modal form did not respond to my submit button .. after form action= "some action" it should atleast respond to my submit button action

Comment: I put different action too i.e create action this time browser recognised the path but the modal form didn't respond just stagnant form

Comment: If you inspect the form element (right click > inspect element) in your browser, does it display the action path correctly?

Comment: yeaa it does show.. action as action="/curated_items/duplicate" but when i click submit nothing happens :(